# Vuetify form reset function gives an error

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I want to reset vuetify form but when I call reset function it gives me an error -> Property 'reset' does not exist on type '{}' How can I reset a form using composition-api

[image: code]

Comment: Can you post it as code please. Also, ESLint is giving you an error, what is it?

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite know if this is what you mean, but if you want to reset a Vuetify form:

> "I want to reset vuetify form"

this should do: `this.$refs.form.reset()`

> The `v-form` component has three functions that can be accessed by setting a ref on the component. A ref allows us to access internal methods on a component, for example, `<v-form ref="form">`. `this.$refs.form.validate()` will validate all inputs and return if they are all valid or not. `this.$refs.form.reset()` will clear all inputs and reset their validation errors. `this.$refs.form.resetValidation()` will only reset input validation and not alter their state.

documentation:
[here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#validation-with-submit-26-clear)